# Select only needed array in array object Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have this sample document , where i want to select the time where the `status` == `start` .if status start is not present in the document   the current time should be taken in the aggregate stage.
if I use `$filter` then I'm not able to use the `$Log` further, because it's being filtered.
`$elemMatch` can't be used in `$project` stage.

```json
{
  "id": "64f142e1d224858b66c9d987",
  "Log": [{
      "status": "Start",
      "time": "09/02/2023 06:17:51",
      "ISOdate": "2023-09-02T00:47:51.420Z",
    }, {
      "status": "Hold",
      "time": "09/02/2023 06:17:57",
      "ISOdate": "2023-09-02T00:47:57.701Z",
    }, {
      "status": "Holdrelease",
      "time": "09/03/2023 07:17:11",
      "ISOdate": "2023-09-03T01:47:11.662Z",
    }, {
      "status": "pause",
      "time": "09/03/2023 07:21:11",
      "ISOdate": "2023-09-03T01:51:11.662Z",
    },
    {
      "status": "pauserelease",
      "time": "09/03/2023 07:38:11",
      "ISOdate": "2023-09-03T01:58:11.662Z",
    },
    {
      "status": "Finish",
      "time": "09/03/2023 07:59:46",
      "ISOdate": "2023-09-03T02:29:46.841Z",
    }
  ]
}
```

```
output needed as
[{
 StartTime : "09/02/2023 06:17:51",
 Log : [{...}]
},
{
 StartTime : "current_time",
 Log : [{...}]
}]
```

Tried using `$filter` but the array `Log` is needed for further use.

`$elemMatch` can't be used in `$project` stage.

please suggest apart using `$unwind`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Select the time like as a variable for use elsewhere within the pipeline? It'd be helpful if you provided the current pipeline and the desired logic so that we can get a better understanding of your requirements

Comment: actually the start time is needed just to match documents between the dates.

Comment: Consider refactoring your schema to store individual documents at `Log` level if you are frequently querying at `Log` level. In this way, you can build your queries easier and gain performance benefits with proper indexing.

Comment: So the client has a date and you want to check to make sure that it is between the `Start` and `Finish` log entries? That should be doable pretty directly using the $gte and $lte operators. Assuming Start and Finish are always the earliest and latest Log entries, then you probably don't even need the (pair of) $elemMatch operator(s) either. Performance probably won't be great long-term though since index scan will only be bounded on one side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `$reduce` to iterate through the `Log` array and conditionally set the accumulator to the start time.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "StartTime": {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$Log",
              "initialValue": null,
              "in": {
                "$cond": {
                  "if": {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.status",
                      "Start"
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": "$$this.time",
                  "else": "$$value"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "current_time"// or $$NOW if you want current time
          
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uW5xVs2L3wf)

Comment: Hey , appreciate your answer here. But for the else block it is'nt responding as expected. for example it'll always go for else even if the condition is true when i remove "$$value" .

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/yrSuiM8Faun  in this example , one document contain start status but executes else block...@ray extremely sorry for my poor explanation

Comment: So..is there any alternate solution for this problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255345/discussion-between-sachin-ganeshkar-and-ray).

Comment: @Sachinganeshkar updated the answer. For your case, you should be adding a `$ifNull` guard out side if the final value of `$$value` remains `null`.